# Variance of Ito Integral when the integrand is a function of a different Wienner process

Tags: probability, integration, variance

I need to find the expression for variance of the integral with the following form:

$\int_0^T X_tdW_{2t}$

when $X_t=f(W_{1t})$ and both $W_{1t}$ and $W_{2t}$ are defined on the same sample space and are correlated. More specifically, is it still possible to use (a version of) Ito Isometry that would take the correlation into account?

Comment: As long as the integrand $X_t$ is adapted to a filtration which is admissible for $W_{2t}$, you can apply Itô's isometry. Note that you need this measurability assumption in any case in order to make sense of the integral.

Comment: @saz, makes sense, completely.  Just as a follow up. So, I do not need to include correlation coefficient anywhere then?